# "Task (agetty) :1694 blocked for more than 120 seconds"during boot

Tags: boot, 15.04

I ve been getting this mesaage constantly ( in my lenevo z 560,  if it matters)  during boot process of Ubuntu 15.04 . It has been hours...Thanks in advance for any help!